# How can I replace space with another string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var str = '                  abc';
str.replace(" ","");
```

but it is not working.

Comment: that should say "replace", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have **spelling error**:

```
replce
```

You should do:

```
var str = ' abc';
str = str.replace(/ /g,"");
```

The `/g` is global modifier which will replace the specified text throughout the given string.

---

Alternatively, you can use `split` and `join` like this:

```
var str = ' abc';
str = str.split(" ").join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s='anishmarokey';
s.replace('a','b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by spaces and get the second part of the split string.

```
var newstr = str.split(" ");
str = newstr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in any browser url

```
javascript:alert('strin g'.replace(/ /g, ''));
```

You need to use regex, not plain strings for js string.replace

```
var str = ' abc'; str = str.replace(/ /g, '');
```

Comment: The second statement won’t do what you apparently expect it to do: `String.replace` _returns_ the modified string, it doesn’t change the string in-place.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str = ' abc';
str=str.replace(/ /g,"");
```